# Having issues with my php email script

Tags: php, email

Here is the webpage that I am helping with: http://www.sertomachilicookoff.com/

The VIP list signup isn't working for some reason. I need it to where you enter you email, you hit submit, and your email address disappears while you a popup code that state you have successfully entered your email and so on.

My issue is that when you enter your email and hit submit, nothing happens. It doesn't even seem to be linked to the php script which I am confused by.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "info@testing.com";
$email_subject = "VIP Subscription";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "There was an error with your submission";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(
    !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    died('There was an error with your submission');       
}

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thanks for signup up for the Newsletter!

<?php
}
?>
```

And here is the html code/script

```
<div class="vip-signup">
        <div class="text">
            Signup to receive updates<br />
            and offers 
        </div>
        <script language="Javascript">
function validate(){
var allok = true;
document.vip.Submit.disabled="disabled";
return true;
}
</script>
<form name="vip" method="Post" action="vip/vip.php" onSubmit="return validate();">


            <div class="form">
            <input type="edit" name="email"   value="Enter your email address">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="Submit"></button>
          </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$_POST['email']` - `name="Email__1"` - *cough* `type="edit"` *huh?*

Comment: doh! Fixed that in my code, but still not working...

Comment: Change `type="edit"` to `type="text"`

Comment: Changed it... still not working.